# Selenium starts running slower and slower

Tags: javascript, performance, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium script written in Python that goes to a site, and scrolls the page to get it to load more data, similar to any social feed. The problem is that the more it scrolls, the more it loads, and the slower the script runs. This makes sense because the DOM is getting bigger and bigger. As a fix I run some code that looks like this:

```
driver.execute_script('''
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('post_container');
while(a.length > 20){
    a[0].remove();
}
''')
```

So now, it can load a bunch of posts. Log some information about those posts, remove those posts from the DOM and then scroll the page to load more posts. This helped immensely. However, I am still noticing that after this script runs for 15 minutes or so, that it is still slowing down significantly, meaning that DOM manipulations are slowing down; finding elements, hovering on elements, removing elements, etc.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the DOM after some elements have been added? Could it be that you're missing some other elements that are added? Maybe container divs of `post_container`? It would help if you can paste a sample of DOM structure here.

Comment: I have compared the DOM after 50 iterations and it looks the exact same. I'll try it again with 500 iterations, but so far it doesn't look like anything is growing...

Comment: Also what browser are you using Selenium to automate? `PhantomJS`, for example, is infamous for its high memory consumption. If you're using it, try switching to Chrome or FF and see if it fixes the issue, maybe it's not your code after all.

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: Does this happen if you run the same test manually?